# How to see the whole url in table view

Tags: ios, url, tableview, xcode4.4

I have some urls in my tableView...What can I do to see not cut urls like: "http://bla-bla-bla.com/bla..."?

I need to see this in my table view: "http://bla-bla-bla.com/bla-bla-bla/bla-bla-bla.png"

Thank you very much!

here is the part of the code, where I input the data:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"LinkID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }

    NSData *n = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[[NSURL alloc]initWithString: [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];

    cell.textLabel.text = [n description];

    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to allow the table cell text to resize to fix the text.

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    cell.textLabel.minimumFontSize = 8; // any smaller and it's too hard to read
}
```

You may also wish to change the label's `lineBreakMode`. It may be better to use `NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle` instead of the default `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail`.

Another option might be to setup a multi-line label and use character wrapping for the long URL.

Comment: ok! Thank you! But it hasn't helped, also if I use any custom options for tableView, should I write somth like "initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyle" not with Default?

Comment: With the changes I suggested, is the text appearing smaller at least? The text may be too long to fit. You can try a smaller minimum font size if you want.